# Python Regex with requirements of both extension and contained string

Tags: python, regex

I would like to monitor files that match these 2 requirements using regex (Since I am using watchdog RegexMatchingEventHandler):

1. must end with `.bson` or `.bson.gz` (aka, extension requirement), like `regexes = ['\.bson.?'],`
2. filename must contain `2017`

Instead of a full program, I would like to use Regex as a string input.

Can anyone offer ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture them using a regex like this:

```
regex = r'.*2017.*\.bson(\.gz)?$'
```

Explanation: The `.*` before and after 2017 matches any character and can repeat any number of times. `(\.gz)?` specifies that `.gz` is optional.

Demonstration:

```
In [2]: fnames = ['sdfa2017sdfa.bson', 'asdf.bson', '2017aa.bson.gz']

In [3]: filtered_files = [f for f in fnames
                          if re.search(r'.*2017.*\.bson(\.gz)?$', f)]

In [4]: filtered_files
Out[4]: ['sdfa2017sdfa.bson', '2017aa.bson.gz']
```

Comment: I tried `print(re.match('.2017..bson(.gz)?', '2017.bson.gz'))`, and it returns `None`...

Comment: try `re.match(r'.*2017.*\.bson(\.gz)?', '.2017..bson(.gz)?')`. You need to put your regular expression as the first argument to `re.match`

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong as well... try `fnames = ['sdfa2017sdfa.bson.it', 'asdf.bson', '2017aa.bson.gz']`, and it still returns out `'sdfa2017sdfa.bson.it`

Comment: So, it should end with either `.bson` or `.bson.gz`? In that case, you just need to add `^` to the end of your regex, specifying that the string should end. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, end with either `.bson` or `.bson.gz`. No, your answer is not correct as well... now it returns nothing.

Comment: Oops, I had to add `$` instead of `^`. Fixed.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you for your patience!